# Top level transitions in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, material-design

I want to create a layout in which I have a `BottomNavigationBar` that is used to navigate between five top-level views.

I want to have a transition like the one found in the material design guidelines for top-level peer transitions.

[Link](https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#peer-transitions)

First the current view is faded out, then the selected view is faded in. The problem is that flutter doesn't seem to have more than two steps in a tween animation, meaning that I can't change the opacity from 1.0 to 0.0, then back to 1.0 (Like CSS @keyframes).

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this? Should I use something other than Tween?

I've tried using multiple Tween animations and changing what the `Opacity` widget's `opacity` value mid-animation, but doing that doesn't even animate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Stack for that. This stack should contain both the widget to fade out and the widget to fade in. Create two Tweens controlled by the same animation controller, one fading out (going from 1.0 to 0.0), one for fading in. Do this in `initState()` from the state of an stateful widget:

```
_animationController =
    AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
_fadeIn = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);
_fadeOut = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(_animationController);
```

(The State needs to use the mixin `TickerProviderStateMixin` or `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`).

With widget a to fade out and b to fade in, the widget to be returned by your build-method will look like:

```
Stack(children: [
  FadeTransition(
    child: a,
    opacity: _fadeOut,
  ),
  FadeTransition(
    child: b,
    opacity: _fadeIn,
  )
]);
```

Eventually you start the animation by calling

```
_animationController?.reset();
_animationController?.forward();
```

from your build-method.

Don't forget to dispose the controller from within the dispose-method of your widget's state.

You may want to construct a general purpose fading widget, which would be a stateful widget with the state inheriting some flavor of `TickerProviderMixin`.

If you want to have such an animation as a routing transition, then look [here](https://medium.com/@agungsurya/create-custom-router-transition-in-flutter-using-pageroutebuilder-73a1a9c4a171). The example given there uses slide transitions but it should be easy to replace those with FadeTransitions for fading out and in.

Edit: found the widget AnimatedSwitcher in the Flutter Widget Library, which does exactly what you want. It is the general purpose widget I spoke of.